# Help with convergence of a recursive sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, problem-solving

We define a sequence of real numbers $\{ x_{n}\} $ in a recursive form where $ x_{0} = 0$ and $$ x _{n} =  \frac{x_{n-1} ^2+2}{3}$$ for $ n \geq 1.$

We need to prove that this sequence converges and to calculate $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} x_{n}.$

I think I know how to do the second part, the part of the limit.
Suppose that $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} x_{n} = L .$ Then $ L = \frac{L^2 +2}{3}$ and we find the solution for $L$ (the possible solutions are $L =1$ or $L =2$).

But of course, all of this depends on the first part, showing the convergence of the sequence, and I don't know how to begin with this particular sequence.
All I can see is that $ x_{0} \lt x_{1} ,$ that  $\frac {2}{3}$ is a lower bound of the sequence and that the sequence slowly increases (evidently, at some point the sequence increases so little that it has an upper bound at $L = 1$ or $2,$ most probably $2$).

I would appreciate some suggestions on how to solve it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a hint, try to show that

- $0 \leq x_n < 1$ for any $n$;
- $x_{n + 1} > x_n$ for any $n$.

Prove the above statements by induction on $n$.

Comment: The increasing part : When n=1, then $x_{1} = 2/3 \gt x_{0} = 0 $. Let n=k and suppose $x_{k} \lt x_{k+1} $. Then $x_{k+1} = \frac{(x_{k}^2 +2)}{3} \lt  x_{k+2} = \frac{(x_{k+1}^2 +2)}{3} $ by inductive hypothesis ($ x_{k} \lt x_{k+1}$), right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 4):

It is clear that $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}, x_n>0.$

Let us prove that the sequence is increasing.
For any $n\geq 2$ is
$$x_{n+1}-x_n=\frac{(x_{n}-x_{n-1})(x_{n}+x_{n-1})}{3}$$
Hence the difference $(x_{n+1}-x_n)$ has constant sign, which is positive because $x_1>x_0.$ The sequence is increasing.

Now, $x_0<1.$ By induction, from $x_n<1$ we deduce $$x_{n+1}<\frac{1+2}{3}=1.$$

The sequence is increasing and bounded from above by $1.$

Answer (score 3):

A simple inductive argument shows $x_n<1$ for all $n$. Further, note that
$$x_{n+1}-x_n=\frac{x_n^2+2}{3}-x_n=\frac{(x_n-1)(x_n-2)}{3}>0$$
Thus, $\{x_i\}$ is a bounded increasing sequence and hence, converges.